# How can I run a particular service that depend_on the list of services that user specifically wants (dynamically)

Tags: docker, docker-compose

I've a docker-compose.yml file that has multiple services. One of the service depends on other services before spinning up, but what I want to achieve is to dynamically depend upon services that the user wants. I don't want to hard code the services that it depends on, rather get those services from user. Is this possible?

Currently my docker-compose.yml file looks like this: -

```
version: '3'
services:
  rabbitmq:
    image:
    profiles:
      - abc

  db:
    image:
    profiles:
      - def

  kafka:
    image:
    depends_on:
      - def
      - abc
```

Instead, I want kafka to depend on the services that user wants. Let's say the user wants kafka to depend only on "def", then kafka should run only after "def" profile is up and running. How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

Being able is possible...
The question here is rather what you want to achieve with it.

Normally, the services are usually given separately and there it is already marked that other services depend. This is achieved with what you indicated:

```
depends_on:
  - def
```

If you want to make it dynamic without adding the `depends_on` tag, you can do it by listening to the user (when using `docker-compose up`) and running a script that adds the depends. But I honestly do not know in what situation I would want to do that

**I insist that you rethink what you want to do or rephrase the question**